# App won't build? DebugResources error?

Tags: java, android

Here is my problem
Can anyone help?
Ive tried changing the build version on gradle but it still doesnt run

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHuCm.jpg

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.872 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 1220063698): libpng error: Not a PNG file

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.771 secs

WHEN I TRY TO CLEAN BUILD:

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library'.
> Failed to create parent directory 'P:\BudgetWiseApp\app\build' when creating directory 'P:\BudgetWiseApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.896 secs
```

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, please copy the *complete* output (lower left corner of your screen) into your question. Only half of the important information is visible in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Your log shows this:

> AAPT err(Facade for 1220063698): libpng error: Not a PNG file

This means that somewhere you have an image resource that is not a PNG.

The log *usually* shows which file is causing the problem, but you might need to run with the `--stacktrace` option (e.g. `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`).

If that still doesn't show the file name, you will need to look through your drawable folders for images that aren't PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Clean Project

Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: Failed to clean build !

Comment: Which Gradle version you are use?

Comment: 23.0.0 in the module app

Comment: You have such string "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x' " in build.gradle file.

Comment: What do you have instead x.x.x ?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: can you update your gradle 2.0 like that : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'  than clean project and rebuild project

Comment: sometimes if you delete any dependency it will show error like yours, be careful when deleting dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the images in your drawable is in png format.
you can convert any image in png format just by opening with a image editor and save as png.